# Searching for artifacts with Maven POM property in Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have some customer properties in the POM files of the artifacts in my Artifactory.

```
<project>
  <properties>
        <enabled>true</enables>
        <push-to-prod>true</push-to-prod>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Is there any way I can search for artifacts matching these in Artifactory API?
Some thing like this?

```
items.find(
    {
       "@pom.enabled" : {"$eq" : "true"}
    })
```

Comment: tried `{"module.property.@enabled" :  "true"}` ?

Comment: @stefan-rasmusson Any luck with this? I have similar need to find malformed poms with ${revision} tokens accidently embedded in projects

Comment: @SamHendley no I found out I actually needed something else then this. I have not tried the suggestion from xerx593, have you?